# Does Visual Studio 2008 can produce/edit local reports(RDLC) for SQL Reporting Services 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, rdlc

Is there way to edit local reports (RDLC) from Reporting Services 2008 with Visual Studio 2008? Now it says that Report element was not found (this is due different schemas).

For me this question is actual, because I want provide my customer with ability to design or customize reports with Report Builder 2.0.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but have you removed 2005 report designer and management studio after installing 2008?

Comment: I never actually had 2005 report designer or management studio. Visual Studio 2008 use this format by default.

Comment: I see now, have you tried renaming the file .rdlc -> .rdl and opening in builder 2.0?

Comment: No, but I will try, thanks fro the idea. I will return back in few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The SQL server BI studio is actually visual studio. Once I installed VS Pro, the BI studio simply "merged" into it.

**UPDATE**
From SQL server books online:

> Upgrade will not delete old log files,
>   the obsolete RSWebApplication.config
>   file, or virtual directory settings in
>   IIS. Upgrade will not remove SQL
>   Server 2005 Report Designer,
>   Management Studio, or other client
>   tools. If you no longer require them,
>   be sure to remove these files and
>   tools after upgrade is finished.

Comment: Sure but this true for RDL, RDLC is still 2005. One second I will update question.

Comment: The problem that RDLC editor is feature of the Visual Studio, not of the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Local reports (RDLC) are rendered by the ReportViewer control, which is a VS 2008 component and is present with our without SSRS (2008).

So, if you are asking if VS 2008 can produce reports (RDLC) that render locally in the VS 2008 ReportViewer control, the answer is yes (but it uses the 2005 schema).

If you are asking if the SSRS Report Editor can create RDLs that render in the VS 2008 ReportViewer control (for instance by renaming them to RLDC, the way in worked with VS 2005 and SSRS 2005), the answer is no (because they use the 2008 schema).

The difference - if you add a new report to a web project, for instance, you are using the VS report designer and it will create a 2005 RDLC schema that renders in the 2008 control.

If you add a new report to a ReportServer project, you are using the SSRS report designer that will create a 2008 RDL schema that is not compatible.

Comment: I am asking how to use RDLC 2008 in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: You can't - the schemas are different. This my question and the response on MSDN http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/e824dd63-4f4c-4810-a2e2-d72710fda78a/#ede7b504-57d0-4099-8f18-6cb3ebe3fbff.